# How to Calculate Distance between points from a reference point using R?

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

I have this data frame `individual_dets` which has some lat and long values in it. This is the dataframe

```
individual_dets = structure(list(location = c("ARB-04", "BIRCHY HEAD", "Boca1", 
"BON-AR-S2", "BON-AR-S2", "BON-W-S5"), month = structure(c(12L, 
10L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), detection_count = c(3L, 
256L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), num_unique_tags = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), total_res_time_in_seconds = c(0, 1182040, 0, 2732221, 0, 
0), latitude = c(24.94808, 44.5713, 26.32559, -49.27732, -49.27732, 
-49.27985), longitude = c(-80.45412, -64.03512, -80.07108, 69.48038, 
69.48038, 69.47853)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    location = c("ARB-04", "BIRCHY HEAD", "Boca1", "BON-AR-S2", 
    "BON-AR-S2", "BON-W-S5"), month = structure(c(12L, 10L, 10L, 
    8L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

However, my dataframe has 4247 observations.

The lat and long values are for coordinates across the ocean in the NW Atlantic. I am trying to calculate the distance from Halifax of these lat and long values.

I have been told to use this function `snap points to line` and then use `lappy` but I am looking at the structure and I am so lost. Does anyone understand how to code using the function `snap points to line` and lappy to get approximate distance?

Comment: What package is `snap points to line` in? This is not a valid function name in r since it contains spaces. I did find `snapPointsToLines` in `maptools` but it specifically warns "This function does not work with geographic coordinates."

Comment: Ok that was the one I was suggested... I didn't notice. That's probably why it wasn't working for me. Do you know of any other functions I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `st_distance()` from the `sf` package:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

individual_dets_sf <- st_as_sf(individual_dets, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
                               crs = 4326) %>% 
  ungroup()
halifax <- data.frame("longitude" = -63.5752, "latitude" = 44.6488)
halifax_sf <- st_as_sf(halifax, 
                       coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
                       crs = 4326,
                       remove = FALSE) 

individual_dets_sf_2 <- individual_dets_sf %>% 
  mutate(distances = st_distance(., halifax_sf, by_element = TRUE))

individual_dets_sf_2$distances

Units: [m]
[1]  2664402.84    37510.33  2513963.08 16466708.65 16466708.65 16466623.17
```

If you want to visualize it (Halifax in blue):

```
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(individual_dets_sf_2 %>% mutate(distances = units::drop_units(distances))) + tm_dots(col = "distances") +
  tm_shape(halifax_sf) + tm_dots(col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: in the ```st_as_sf``` function for the ```coords = c()``` do I keep the ```"longitude", "latitude``` ? right now I'm getting the error message ```Error in st_as_sf.data.frame(individual_dets, coords = c("longitude",  : 
  missing values in coordinates not allowed``` but I have way too many observations to put them in individually.

Comment: Yes, you need those. They provide the geographic information (i.e., the coordinates) necessary to calculate distances to other places. If you have rows that are missing longitude and/or latitude data, you'll need to remove those points before using `st_as_sf()`.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Sorry I'm actually getting all 0m? in the distance column

Comment: Ah, I miscopied something (the `crs = 4326`) was missing.  Can you try that first code block again?

Comment: ok great it worked... is that in miles or meters? and also how do I keep all my original columns? It has filtered out the lat and long values which I still need.

Comment: meters.  Here's a function `measurements::conv_units()` for converting the units and a list of abbreviations: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/measurements/versions/1.4.0/topics/conv_unit

Comment: Is there anyway to keep all the original data in the dataframe along with the new calculated distances?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207510/discussion-between-kristen-cyr-and-eugene-chong).